# Automating hybrid app (android) with appium using python

Tags: python, automation, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am writing automation testing for my hybrid android app created with ionic framework. But during running testing I am unable to start app using its activity. Here is error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown
>   server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
>   error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Activity used
>   to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists
>   and is a launchable activity

Here is my desired capabilities code ........

```
class TestLoginLogout(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '7.0'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'ZY223XQMWZ'
        desired_caps['app'] = PATH('/home/martial/DYFO/dyfo.apk')
        desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'dyfolabs.automatioo'
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = "dyfolabs.automation.MainActivity"
        desired_caps['context'] = 'WEBVIEW'
        desired_caps['noReset'] = 'true'
        desired_caps['fullReset'] = 'false'
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Please help me I am stuck here. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Download selenium for python from here: `https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/`
and appium for python from here: http://appium.io/downloads.html

Include these into your project and try again